# Webclient fail in .NET Core/5 but not in .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net-core

Have an odd one here... I have the following C# code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var url = "https://www.nordea.com/wemapp/api/fi/lists/currency/electronicExchangeFI.dat";
        var result = DownloadData(url);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}

private static string DownloadData(string url)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    byte[] xmlData = webClient.DownloadData(url);
    webClient.Dispose();
    string data = string.Empty;
    if (xmlData.Length > 0)
    {
        data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(xmlData);
    }
    return data;
}
```

With this specific website (some exchange rate data) the above fails as a .NET Core/5 Console app, but it works as expected in .NET Framework (4.7)

In .NET Core I get following exception on method `webClient.DownloadData(url);` -

> An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

with Inner Exception being

> The response ended prematurely, with at least 1 additional bytes
> expected.

---

I've also tried using `new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url).Result;` but that fails in both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Does anyone have any clue why this is (it must be something with URL but how can one tell why and what to change in the request)?

Comment: Httpclient is the modern way to go. But you should use a static single instance, instead of creating a new object. And you should await the async method. Don't use result.

Comment: I know that. This is just test-code

Comment: "That fails" is not a valid problem statement. **Be specific.**

Comment: @IanKemp: As mentioned it throw an exception: "An exception occurred during a WebClient request". with inner exception: "The response ended prematurely, with at least 1 additional bytes expected."

Comment: If you "know that", why aren't you doing it? This is just wrong, as you are getting the Result while the Task isn't finished. edit: and if somebody asks you to be specific, repeating the information you already gave is not the right think to do. *Help people help you.*

Comment: @JHBonarius: Because that is not the root cause here. The question is about why the code acts differently in .NET Framework (works) and throws an exception in .NET Core/5... but only for this specific URL. I kept the code as simple as possible to avoid confusion

Comment: It seems to be reproducable in .Net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kDZ896
If changed to 4.7.2 it works.

Comment: Things have been rewritten ground up for .NET core. Maybe there already was an issue with the code. Or something else changed. Note: the exception you show is likely the outer exception. You should look at the inner exception to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @JHBonarius: The inner exception is: The response ended prematurely, with at least 1 additional bytes expected. There is no further exceptions.

Comment: @Magnus: Thank you for confirming that is not just me that is going mad :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that server's response violates the HTTP specification, according to [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler):

> [ProtocolViolation] Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 12,803 bytes, but server sent 12,802 bytes.

The .NET Framework's HTTP stack is notorious for silently tolerating problems like this, while .NET Core features a completely rewritten stack that is much less forgiving. In this case it seems that Framework either isn't particularly trusting of the response's `Content-Length` or simply ignores it, while Core depends on its correctness (I'd guess for performance optimizations).

While some may argue that Core's behaviour is less convenient (especially since there's no way to opt out of it), the fact is that Framework's leniency is precisely the kind of thing that allows such broken behaviour to propagate and remain unfixed. Core is doing the right thing here, and I'm honestly baffled how the people running that server managed to screw up something as simple as `Content-Length`... and that they apparently never tested it's correct...

Your only options are to contact the server admin and get them to fix their brokenness, or use lower-level methods of reading that server's response in a way that bypasses the invalid `Content-Length`. An example of the following is given below (**no guarantees regarding correctness or performance are provided; I tested this once**):

```csharp
// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests
var client = new HttpClient();
var responseStream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://www.nordea.com/wemapp/api/fi/lists/currency/electronicExchangeFI.dat");
int bufferSize = 1024;
var streamBytes = new byte[0];
var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

while (true)
{
    var readCount = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    var temp = new byte[streamBytes.Length + readCount];
    Array.Copy(streamBytes, temp, streamBytes.Length);
    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, temp, temp.Length - readCount, readCount);
    streamBytes = temp;

    if (readCount < buffer.Length)
        break;
}

var responseText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(streamBytes);
Console.WriteLine(responseText.Length); // 12802, the actual length
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using CopyTo with a memory stream in your proposal? That would make this tremendously easier, but I might be missing some intricacy.

Comment: I always like to add the [proper usage of `HttpClient`](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). I still see a lot of code around having multiple `using` blocks.

Comment: @Voo `Stream.CopyTo` raises the same exception reported by the asker because it attempts to read to the response's reported `Content-Length`, which fails because the **actual** length of the content is 1 byte shorter. Manually reading the stream in 1KB chunks as I'm doing, completely bypasses the erroneous `Content-Length`.

Comment: @JHBonarius As MSDN includes the same recommendations nowadays, I see no value in continuing to point users to that article.

Comment: @Ian Oh I wasn't aware that CopyTo used that optimization. I thought it was simply calling read in chunks until 0 was returned as we all used to do in the good old days. That reminds me though that your check is I think incorrect and you should explicitly check for 0.. partial reads are valid if I read the documentation correctly.

Comment: @Voo `CopyTo` doesn't - I believe that it asks the backing stream for its length, and if present uses that value. The problem is that the `Stream` returned by `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` is implemented to provide `Content-Length` as stream length. My code will handle partial reads correctly AFAIK, as 0 < 1024.

Comment: @ian Isn't there a problem if say the stream has say 200 bytes left, but read only returns the first 50 for any reason (this is add I understand it contractually fine behavior in so usual streaming APIs)? Doesn't your implementation stop and not read the remaining 150 bytes? I'm on my phone so kind of hard to check these things in more detail.

Comment: @IanKemp Thank you for the explanation... I will contact the provider and ask them to fix it :-)